# Есть ли в Phpstorm автоформатирование кода PHP/JS/CSS?

Tags: phpstorm, php, редактор

Есть ли в Phpstorm автоформатирование кода PHP/JS/CSS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+L

Comment: в 7 версии не работает.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk уже давно 8.1 вышла. :)

Comment: В 8-й версии также не работает.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, все работает. Может, вы другую схему используете?

Comment: Для PHP кода.

Comment: И для PHP работает, проверил в 6-й и 8-й версии, а если с мака, нужно нажимать command+alt+L.

Comment: Странно - у меня не работает. Может, нужно выделить весь код?

Comment: Встряну в беседу - попробуйте дважды нажать ``Ctrl+Alt+L``, у меня только так открывается.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, ну, если не трудно, то попробуйте выделить и нажать. :) Или вы думаете, при нажатии заветных кнопок phpstorm без спроса весь проект отредактирует как надо?

Comment: А еще можно попробовать вырезать весь код и вставить. У меня он автоматом css/html точно форматирует (это webstorm). Не знаю, как с PHP, но phpstorm должен форматировать тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Code -> Reformat code
Alt + F8 (2017.2.1 version)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> если phpstorn8 + ubuntu.